# AsyncHttpResponse ASP.Net Response

Tags: android, asp.net, http, loopj

I'm developing an Android application that send some string via Http Post to ASP page with a library AsyncHttpResponse (loopj).

```
AsyncHttpClient device = new AsyncHttpClient();
...
device.post("http://aspspider.info/remod/webroot/provaNome.aspx",
             new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        text.setText(response);  //TextView on activity
                    }
             });
```

The Asp.net page (provaNome.aspx) should return a string (ex. "holla") with a command

```
Response.Write("holla");
```

The communication work, but the response return a html page (with title "Configuration Error") and not only the string. Where I find my string return?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Why dont you change your header to JSON, and write  your response in JSON

Comment: Sounds like there's a configuration error with your asp site somewhere. Try posting to the page through Fiddler (or maybe a browser but that would be GET and not POST). Fiddler should give you a WebView of the response and in that an error.

Comment: Thank you! With JSON the communication work!:) But the time is very slow, about 2minutes D:.. why? Thank you again:)